okhttp3.mockwebserver 4.12.0, missing readreadUtf8
Please Im having an issue can't figure what Im missing:
RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest();
request.getBody().readUtf8()
Intellij, spring boot unit test is telling me can't resolve method readUtf8
any help will be greatly appreciated
This is the decompiled RecordedRequest.class. I dont see readUtf8
enter image description here
I tried mvn clean package, I tried invalidate cache in intellij, not luck so far. Please note that Im encountring this in scope of migrating to spring boot 3.0

Ok I believe I figured the issue. Maybe this will help someone else. It looks like starting okio 3.4.0, readUtf8 has stopped being part of okio buffer java .class. Maye this is due to the kotlin refactoring. So In order to resolve this issue I had to add this dependency in my pom file:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

